# Voting on questions. When should you give a upvote

Tags: discussion, support, questions, voting

I makes me mad that all the (humbly thankful for their input) gurus on here and they haven't learned that if you think a question deserves an answer it also deserves a upvote...........

GUYS you should give questions a upvote if it deserves an answer!!!!

I don't know how many questions I have without any votes but plenty of answers or help....

Comment: See the answers at https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3135/117549 for some counterpoints.

Answer (score 13):

Upvote button hover text:

> This question shows research effort; it is helpful and clear

The fact that someone answers a question does not, *de facto*, make it a good question. Questions may have answers and show zero research effort, or be borderline incomprehensible and people will still answer them.

Upvotes are the *only* signifier of quality.

<sup>Answered, but not upvoted...</sup>

Comment: It should be if the question deserves an answer then it deserves a upvote

Comment: @somethingSomething  but it's not.